# Ошибка при форматировании длинной строки в Python

Tags: python, строки

Получаю ошибку при форматировании длинной строки:

> ).format(myparam = 5) ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name

Я так понимаю это из-за конфликта `{}`.Как избавиться от нее? И как сделать эту строку форматированной?

```
code = ('''
while (i < 25){
    var offset = i*100 + {myparam};
    i = i + 1;
}
''').format(myparam = 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно экранировать знаки `{` и `}` с помощью дублирования соответствующего символа:

```
In [5]: print('''
while (i < 25){{
    var offset = i*100 + {myparam};
    i = i + 1;
}}
'''.format(myparam = 5))

while (i < 25){
    var offset = i*100 + 5;
    i = i + 1;
}
```